# PDO connection failing, How to connect it

Tags: php, pdo

Can you please point out what I am doing wrong in following statement?

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=my-db-name','host=localhost', 'username', 'password', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci';"));
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

There is syntax error. I know it would be a silly question but i am kind of stuck here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why didn't you look up php.net/PDO for answers? 2nd argument to the constructor isn't the host.

Comment: ooops, sorry guyz my bad, i fixed it,

Comment: @N.B is there any restriction here to ask question ?

Comment: There is a restriction, but there are no restrictions for me to downvote your question and vote for closing since it's not helping anyone else.

Comment: ok go ahead mate ! and i love your behaviour, keep it up,

Comment: It sucks when you make a stupid mistake that you can correct *on your own* but someone had to tell you. It's surprising that you're willing to argue here with me and you aren't willing to improve yourself on your own. I love your attitude, you are one heck of an intellectual! (oh look, my sarcasm works also).

Comment: no offence mate, we are here to learn, my question may be bad or irrelevant but u cant say i never tried, i am more than willing to improve my self. and thats what **I AM DOING**

Comment: if you think its a stupid question then u can do following things

**Downvote**
**CLOSE IT**
if not then
**suggest some nice ways on how to ask question**

if you cant do any of the above then

**You are not invited here, get the heck out of here**

Comment: Just read the manual next time before asking trivial questions, is it so hard to swallow? It is a stupid question, you probably have the cojones to come up with an answer on your own. Whatever you do, I'm out of here and good luck improving yourself asking for help at the first small stone you trip.

Comment: mind your toungue, i know what i am doing, your next bad coment will lead me to satisfy you with whatever i can say, i am very **GOOD** at it

Comment: If you were any less intelligent, I'd have to water you twice a week.

Comment: and if you were infront of me, i'd have water you right now dumb a**

Comment: you havent seen me mate, you reputation on SO cant help u in ur attitude, i wont stop untill u say sorry

Comment: Sadly, after I press ctrl + w in a few seconds, I'll forget you and trivial problems your mind is battling with.. :/

Comment: you were never invited my dear attention seeker, go water yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing wrong where you are giving you db:name and local host it should be like below

`'mysql:dbname=my-db-name;host=localhost'`   check that i added `;` in it, edit it and try it

Comment: thx for your help mate ! i fixed it, i was missing wot u pointed out

Answer (score 1):

```
new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my-db-name', 'username', 'password' [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

if i'm not wrong it should be something like

```
 $db     = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my-db-name', 'username', 'password', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci';"));
 $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```